# Dealing with single character destroyed gear

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, wealth

My +1 gauntlets got destroyed due to damage from a green slime. As at this level it represents a significant portion of my wealth it puts me behind everyone else.

How do other groups deal with a single character who has lost a significant portion of their wealth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are now however much below your expected wealth-by-level. The system expects you to have gear evaluated at a certain amount of money. The system does not work well (works even *less well*) when these assumptions, that are baked into the design of monsters and other challenges, are not met.

The issues from being under the expected wealth level get worse as you get higher in level, and are (far, far, *far*) worse for mundane classes than for magical classes. Since the item in question was *+1 gauntlets* and this is a significant portion of your wealth, we can assume that 1. you aren’t *very* high level, but high enough that it’s starting to matter a whole lot, and 2. you are likely a mundane class and likely among the weakest out there, since gauntlets/unarmed strikes make relatively poor weapons.

That implies that being below the expected wealth-by-level is a significant issue. You may be incapable of adventuring at the level you previously were able to handle. You may be incapable of keeping up and contributing with your party. You may be sidelined until your wealth is restored to the expected values. You may be forced to put the entire adventure on pause, to drag your entire party away from their goals so that you can take a side-trip to recover what you have lost.

Personally, I consider all of that bad for the game. Personally, I do not use things like green slimes that risk derailing the game in that fashion. Personally, in many cases, I consider such results to be a disrespectful waste of everyone’s time (but context matters a whole lot).

The GM is responsible for wealth. The GM is responsible for encounter design. The GM is responsible for understanding the system and the consequences of various events. The GM is responsible for keeping the game moving. Personally, I do not consider these events to have been a great way of meeting those responsibilities—but it depends a lot on the kind of game you’re playing. In a sandbox campaign, this is perfectly expectable—the entire premise of the game is for the party to set their own goals, figure out their own pace, and for the world itself to be organic and reactive to that. These events are just a reflection of the game and the party is empowered to take the time to recover. In an epic, save-the-world quest type of campaign, this is at best a distraction, taking away from the premise of the game.

So the first thing to do is to talk to the GM, and ensure they understand their responsibilities. Make sure that you are on the same page about how wealth is handled—make for damn sure that they understand that you are now below wealth, that the *+1 gauntlets* you used to have no longer count for anything. Ask what your character knows they can do pro-actively (whether they know places to get replacement gear quickly, whether they have the means to do so, etc.). Make sure the rest of the group is on the same page that you now need to pause the adventure and recover your weapon, or you cannot continue playing as a full, active member of the group (if anyone doubts it, the first enemy with DR/magic would prove the point).

And then do what you have to do—which probably means abandoning whatever dungeon you found the green slime in, going back to town, and buying new gauntlets. Probably you’ll have to borrow money from your party. It possibly means fast-forwarding through a few months of down-time while your character works safe jobs to save up enough for replacements, or at least adventuring under your level for a while.

Comment: I remember having a 5th level character who faced another 5th level NPC, only they have well over 150k in gear. It was not even close to a fair fight.

Answer (score 1):

**Repair, Recoup, Redeem**

Repairing seems to be surprisingly easy. Under the [Pathfinder Reference Document](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems.html), you will have two methods of repairing magical items that are rather pricey relatively cheaply.

> #### Repairing Magic Items
>
> Repairing a magic item requires material components equal to **half the cost to create the item**, and requires half the time. The make whole spell can also repair a damaged (or even a destroyed) magic items—if the caster is high enough level {as in equal or greater than caster level of gauntlets}.

(Emphasis and {} brackets mine)

Recouping your losses is tougher. Losing magical items early on will set you back no matter how independent you feel you might be. Ask for teammates for help on suggestions in the dynamic. It sounds like you lost a bit of armor and therefore need to run a guerilla tactic in strategic combat.

If you are very hurting for that item that helps you that you lost, talk with the DM about how you can recover your wealth. A small side quest that gives the party as a whole a reward, as well as an item specifically designed to replace your lost item, is a cheesy but effective method.

Redeeming favors gained, burning contacts gotten just so you can get your stuff back is a costly price in face-value, having no quest givers because they are still bitter from you mooching every last copper for another set of +2 longswords or a cloak of charisma, etc. would definitely be a downer, but you would be able to have your stuff again. The main thing is if you're desperate enough and the DM can sense it, just like a Klondike bar, you will be tested if you are willing. Or the DM will feel sympathy and toss a new set of gauntlets in a loot pile next chance he gets.

Comment: don't forget the "make whole" spell.

Comment: Repair is not an option as it was destroyed

Comment: I included the make whole spell in the repair block quote. It is able to restore even destroyed magical items it would seem.